# ffprobe get pts of last audio/video packet

Tags: video, ffmpeg, ffprobe, pts

I have an `mov` file that I need to get the ending `pts` for both the audio and video streams. I'm able to do this by doing the following (manually):

`ffprobe -show_packets file.mov`

Which gives me an output like (with many more packets of course):

```
[PACKET]
codec_type=audio
stream_index=0
pts=221184
pts_time=5.015510
dts=221184
dts_time=5.015510
duration=580
duration_time=0.013152
convergence_duration=N/A
convergence_duration_time=N/A
size=304
pos=4833575
flags=K_
[/PACKET]
[PACKET]
codec_type=video
stream_index=1
pts=29800
pts_time=4.966667
dts=29400
dts_time=4.900000
duration=200
duration_time=0.033333
convergence_duration=N/A
convergence_duration_time=N/A
size=20707
pos=4837376
flags=__
[/PACKET]
```

In the scenario above, the ending pts is `221764` for audio and `30000` for video (`pts + duration`).

I was wondering if there was an easy way to either get the final audio/video packet pts directly via ffprobe flags or by intelligently parsing the output.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Run

```
ffprobe -v 0 -show_entries packet=pts,duration -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -read_intervals 999999 -select_streams v video.mp4  | tail -1
```

This will print values in the form of `118231200|3600` where the first value is the pts and the second the duration of the last packet of the video stream.

You just need to make sure the value of `-read_intervals`, in seconds, is equal to or greater than the duration of the file. `999999` is a safe value. The tail is required for video streams since ffprobe will print the entire last GOP.

Comment: Holy crap you rock Gyan! This is perfect!

Comment: This seems to fail with M2TS files if the *latest* packet of a stream is not the *last* packet in that stream in the *physical file*; in other words, if the packets in the physical file are not ordered by PTS. I have just tested it with a few M2TS files that are arranged that way. I have no clue whether other container formats (e.g. mp4, mov, mkv and so on) can suffer from that problem, too.

Comment: Yes, for streams with B-frames, that's a possibility. You can change the `| tail -1` to `| tail -8 | sort -n | tail -1` to account for that.

Comment: I already did something similar. Lucky me that I have installed Cygwin on my Windows machines ;-) But thanks for the `-8`; I didn't know that number yet. And I have to leave away the `-read_intervals` part as it seems, because otherwise ffprobe emits the last frame only (before tailing the output). I'll look into this again.